# How to find attribute value in debugger?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, uibutton

I have a button and would like to know its enabled state while stepping through code.  This doesn't work in the debugger:

```
po self.myButton.enabled
```

It prints:

```
There is no member named enabled.
```

Is there another way to print out its state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gdb doesn't know dot-syntax for properties, but it will evaluate method calls.  -[UIButton enabled] returns a BOOL, which is a scalar type, not an object, so you should use `p` with a type cast, like this:

```
p (BOOL)[[self myButton] enabled]
```

If the property you want to inspect is an object, you can use `po` without the type cast, like this:

```
po [[self myButton] font]
```

Comment: I keep getting the same message: Target does not respond to this message selector.

Comment: Aha.  The UIControl documentation declares the enabled property as "@property(nonatomic, getter=isEnabled) BOOL enabled".  It doesn't use the default getter method.  So try "p (BOOL)[[self myButton] isEnabled]".